# OptaPlanner - The entity was never added to this ScoreDirector error

Tags: optaplanner

I am implementing an algorithm similar to the NurseRoster one in OptaPlanner. I need to implement a rule in drools that check if the `Employee` cannot work more days than the number of days in his `contract`. Since i couldn't figure out how to make this in drools, i decided to write it as a method in a class, and then use it in drools to check if the constraint has been broken. Since i needed a `List` of `ShiftAssignments` in the `Employee` class, i needed to use an `@InverseRelationShadowVariable` that updated that list automatically an `Employee` got assigned to a `Shift`. Since my `Employee` now has to be a `PlanningEntity`, the error `The entity was never added to this ScoreDirector` appeared. I believe the error is caused by my `ShiftAssignment` entity, which has a `@ValueRangeProvider` of `employees` that can work in that `Shift`. I think this is due to the fact that `ScoreDirector.beforeEntityAdded` and `ScoreDirector.afterEntityAdded` were never called, hence the error. For some reason when i removed that range provider from `ShiftAssignment` and put it on `NurseRoster` which is the `@PlanningSolution`, it worked.

Here is the code:

Employee:

```
@InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "employee")
public List<ShiftAssignment> getEmployeeAssignedToShiftAssignments() {
    return employeeAssignedToShiftAssignments;
}
```

ShiftAssignment:

```
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {
    "employeeRange" }, strengthComparatorClass =    EmployeeStrengthComparator.class,nullable = true)
public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

// the value range for this planning entity
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "employeeRange")
public List<Employee> getPossibleEmployees() {
    return getShift().getEmployeesThatCanWorkThisShift();
}
```

NurseRoster:

```
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "employeeRange")
@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
    return employeeList;
}
```

And this is the method i use to update that `listOfEmployeesThatCanWorkThisShift`:

```
public static void checkIfAnEmployeeCanBelongInGivenShiftAssignmentValueRange(NurseRoster nurseRoster) {
    List<Shift> shiftList = nurseRoster.getShiftList();
    List<Employee> employeeList = nurseRoster.getEmployeeList();
    for (Shift shift : shiftList) {
        List<Employee> employeesThatCanWorkThisShift = new ArrayList<>();
        String shiftDate = shift.getShiftDate().getDateString();
        ShiftTypeDefinition shiftTypeDefinitionForShift = shift.getShiftType().getShiftTypeDefinition();
        for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
            AgentDailySettings agentDailySetting = SearchThroughSolution.findAgentDailySetting(employee, shiftDate);
            List<ShiftTypeDefinition> shiftTypeDefinitions = agentDailySetting.getShiftTypeDefinitions();
            if (shiftTypeDefinitions.contains(shiftTypeDefinitionForShift)) {
                employeesThatCanWorkThisShift.add(employee);

            }
        }
        shift.setEmployeesThatCanWorkThisShift(employeesThatCanWorkThisShift);
    }
}
```

And the rule that i use:

```
rule "maxDaysInPeriod"
when
$shiftAssignment : ShiftAssignment(employee != null)
then
int differentDaysInPeriod = MethodsUsedInScoreCalculation.employeeMaxDaysPerPeriod($shiftAssignment.getEmployee());
int maxDaysInPeriod = $shiftAssignment.getEmployee().getAgentPeriodSettings().getMaxDaysInPeriod();
if(differentDaysInPeriod > maxDaysInPeriod)
{
scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, differentDaysInPeriod - maxDaysInPeriod);
}
end
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Isn't it just because the employees are missing from your solution's `getProblemFacts()` method? Note the difference between `add()` and `addAll()`.

Comment: No i believe that's not the case. I have `facts.addAll(employeeList);` added in the NurseRoster class.

Comment: Same error but under different circumstances is occurring here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44193111/the-entity-was-never-added-to-this-scoredirector-exception-during-custom-cloning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has definitely something to do with the solution cloning that is happening when a "new best solution" is created.

I encountered the same error when i implemented custom solution cloning. In my project i have multiple planning entity classes and all of them have references to each other (either a single value or a List). So when solution cloning is happening the references need to be updated so they can point to the cloned values. This is something that the default cloning process is doing without a problem, and thus leaving the solution in a consistent state. It even updates the Lists of planning entity instances in the parent planning entities correctly (covered by the method "cloneCollectionsElementIfNeeded" from the class "FieldAccessingSolutionCloner" from the OptaPlanner core).

Just a demonstration what i have when it comes to the planning entity classes:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class ParentPlanningEntityClass{
    List<ChildPlanningEntityClass> childPlanningEntityClassList;
}

@PlanningEntity
public class ChildPlanningEntityClass{
    ParentPlanningEntityClass parentPlanningEntityClass;
}
```

At first i did not update any of the references and got the error even for "ChildPlanningEntityClass". Then i have written the code that updates the references. When it comes to the planning entity instances that were coming from the class "ChildPlanningEntityClass" everything was okay at this point because they were pointing to the cloned object. What i did wrong in the "ParentPlanningEntityClass" case was that i did not create the "childPlanningEntityClassList" list from scratch with "new ArrayList();", but instead i just updated the elements of the list (using the "set" method) to point at the cloned instances of the "ChildPlanningEntityClass" class. When creating a "new ArrayList();", filling the elements to point to the cloned objects and setting the "childPlanningEntityClassList" list everything was consistent (tested with FULL_ASSERT).

So just connecting it to my issue maybe the list "employeeAssignedToShiftAssignments" is not created from scratch with "new ArrayList();" and elements instead just get added or removed from the list. So what could happen (if the list is not created from scratch) here is that both the working and the new best solution (the clone) will point to the same list and when the working solution would continue to change this list it would corrupt the best solution.