# The entity was never added to this scoreDirector exception during custom cloning

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to implement custom cloning in my solution, i followed the instructions as in the documentation, and i encountered a roadblock in the form of this exception : `The entity was never added to this ScoreDirector. Maybe that specific instance is not in the return values of the PlanningSolution's entity members`. I know that this is not true because before the custom cloning, this exception wasn't thrown.

My `planningClone` method is setup like this :

```
@Override
public Solution planningClone() {
    Solution clonedSolution = new Solution();
    clonedSolution.id = id;
    clonedSolution.code = code;
    clonedSolution.score = score;
    clonedSolution.field1 = field1;
    clonedSolution.field2 = field2;
    ...............
    clonedSolution.fieldN = fieldN;

    List<PlanningEntity1> clonedPlanningEntity1List= new ArrayList<PlanningEntity1>(planningEntity1List.size());
    List<PlanningEntity2> clonedPlanningEntity2List= new ArrayList<PlanningEntity2>(planningEntity1List.size());

    for (PlanningEntity1 planningEntity: planningEntity1List) {
        clonedPlanningEntity1List.add(planningEntity.clone());
    }
    for (PlanningEntity2 planningEntity: planningEntity2List) {
        clonedPlanningEntity1List.add(planningEntity.clone());
    }
    clonedSolution.planningEntity1List = clonedPlanningEntity1List;
    clonedSolution.planningEntity2List = clonedPlanningEntity2List;
    return clonedSolution;
{
```

The clone method for my planning entities is implemented through the Java interface `Cloneable`:

```
protected PlanningEntity clone() {
    try {
        return (PlanningEntity) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Just to be sure, i checked every entity instance and their collections to make sure my cloning was working correctly, and it in fact is.

What step am i missing here?

Comment: Same error but under different circumstances is occurring here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041310/optaplanner-the-entity-was-never-added-to-this-scoredirector-error.

Comment: Why are you using custom cloning? I'd like to understand why, so maybe we can improve the next version's generic cloner so you don't have to any more :) I presume you've seen `@DeepPlanningClone` annotations etc?

Comment: Basically this post is what inspired me to try custom cloning : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170732/solution-cloning-happening-at-steps-that-produce-a-new-best-score-in-a-row . More specifically the second option, cloning only the instances that changed, making it incremental. Unless this is not possible, i believe implementing this will make cloning a decent amount faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is one planning entity pointing to another planning entity from a different class or maybe pointing to a list, than the cloning process needs to take care of the references for those planning entities so they point to the cloned objects.This is something that the default cloning process is doing without a problem, and thus leaving the solution in a consistent state. It even updates the Lists of planning entity instances in the parent planning entities correctly (covered by the method "cloneCollectionsElementIfNeeded" from the class "FieldAccessingSolutionCloner" from the OptaPlanner core).

So for example if we have the next two planning entity classes

```
@PlanningEntity
public class ParentPlanningEntityClass{
    List<ChildPlanningEntityClass> childPlanningEntityClassList;
}

@PlanningEntity
public class ChildPlanningEntityClass{
    ParentPlanningEntityClass parentPlanningEntityClass;
}
```

The "parentPlanningEntityClass" variable needs to be set to point to the cloned object. When it comes to the list "childPlanningEntityClassList" it first needs to be created from scratch with "new ArrayList();" so that both the working and new best solution (the one that is currently getting cloned) don't point to the same list. At the end the newly created list needs to be filled with the cloned objects.